# Does Rails have an instance method on ActiveRecord models that combines "respond_to?" and "send"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have done some googling on it but to no avail.

My scenario is that I have a helper method that takes some options and then renders a commonly used graphical element on the page through a partial, tweaked by the sent in options. Much of these options have different overridable defaults set by the helper, based on the first two required arguments - *object* and *context*.

```
def my_helper(object, context, options = {})
    defaults = { ... }
    defaults[:foo] = "bar" if object.is_a?(SomeObject)
    defaults[:ping] = "pong" if context.eql?(:some_context)
    ...
    render partial: '/path/to/partial', locals: defaults.merge(options)
end
```

While the *context* is all nice and dandy, I have decided to move away from looking at the *object* class and, where plausible, use `respond_to?` rather. What I want to avoid though is having multiple `if object.respond_to?(:foo?) && object.foo?`, and just use something like `if object.respond_to_and_send(:foo?)`, which would return nil if the object cannot respond to the method.

---

**Update**
I forgot to mention that this is a Rails 3.2 application, which is a shame since the updated `try` method in Rails 4, as mentioned in [Holger Just's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20661665/638254), is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>The answer to your question is No.</del> UPD: `object.try(:foo?)` works in Rails 4, as *Holger Just* suggests above.

There are workarounds though. One of them is to create a module with the method you need and extend your context object with it.

```
module SmartResponder
   def respond_to_and_send(method, *args, &block)
     public_send(method, *args, &block) if respond_to?(method)
   end
end
context = [1,2,3]
context.extend(SmartResponder)

context.respond_to_and_send(:to_s)
# => "[1, 2, 3]"
context.respond_to_and_send(:to_sssss)
# => nil
context.respond_to_and_send(:inject, 100) { |x,y| x+y }
# => 106
```

Comment: And that's exactly what is implemented in Rails 4 as `try`. [See the source code for details](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L41-L47).

Comment: I reinvented the wheel :)

Comment: Since I'm using Rails 3.2, `try` won't unfortunately work here. Your snippet does the job!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `try` like this:

```
object.try(:foo?)
```

It will check if `object` responds to `foo?` and if so, calling the method. If `object` does not respond to the method, `try` will return `nil`.

See [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) for details.

Comment: Doesn't the documentation lie? I tried to call `"adas".try(:adadadad)` in rails console and got `NoMethodError: undefined method `adadadad' for "adas":String`.

Comment: @DNNX: The implementation changed in Rails 4. In earlier versions, it always called `__send__` and had an override for `NilClass` where it just returned `nil`. Since Rails4, it actually uses `respond_to?`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Good to know. Seems that my answer is not quite correct then, I'll update it.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but I failed to mention I'm in Rails 3.2 - see my update.

Answer (score 0):

```
object.send(:foo) rescue nil
```

This should do the trick. Be careful of introducing subtle bugs using this technique. (for example if the method call itself raises an error, you will get nil and the actual exception will be hidden)

Comment: as always, `rescue` should only be used when the minority of cases will trigger it.  `rescue` is expensive, and your performance will suffer.

Comment: An even greater issue with the inline rescue is that it will swallow all exceptions which can easily hide real errors. Generally, you should try to avoid it unless you are sure that you are prepared to deal with the hidden exceptions.